# Adjusting BibTeX bibliography style to add space between two authors

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibliographystyle

I am currently modifying the natbib citation style, but am now coming across an issue where there is a missing space in between the first author name and "and" in the case of 2 authors.
More than 2 authors is fine.

[image]

I think I need to specify a case for numnames = 2, but the edits I tried did not work.

Here is my code:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll }{f{.}.}{, jj }" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                {"," *}
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { "~and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

I also have a section supressing periods after author initials, I don't think this interferes but will add it for reference:

```
FUNCTION {no.bib.dots}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\catcode`.=\active\NoBibDots{" swap$ * "}\catcode`.=12" * }
  if$
}

    FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names no.bib.dots ~"." * }
  if$
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `natbib` citation management package does *not* govern the formatting of bibliographic entries. Which bibliography style are you working with and/or have you begun to modify?

Comment: Apologies for getting that wrong - I have begun to modify plainnat.bst